# Added armature bone doesn't export properly in animation

Tags: animation, armature, bones, animation-nodes

**TLDR**: I had an existing armature of a humanoid character, with animations I had already created. I Added an extra bone representing the position of a bag the character carries around and updated the animations. Inside the Blender animation editor everything is fine, the bag position animates as I expect, but the exported animation stays forever at (0,0,0) (in model space).

First, what I expect it to look like (inside blender). The highlighted bone is the new one.

[image]

You can see the bone that represents the bag. The bone's parent is the armature node. It apprears properly inside the armature's list of bones.

Here's what it looks like in-engine. Because the bones are otherwise invisible I added a little red sphere to show the final bone position. The bind pose seems correct (debugging I can see the coordinates match the bone inside blender), but a (0,0,0) animation results at a final bone position between the character's feet, making the bag appear to lie on the floor.

[image]

To get the obvious out of the way, I'm not ruling out issues with either my importing of the FBX mesh, nor animation issues in my engine, though it's worth noting that every other bone works, and the character properly runs and jumps around, whereas the bag stays glued to his feet in spite of sampling the animations the same way. I debugged the import far enough to see that it indeed sees the bone, sees the bind pose correctly, but the animation values seem wrong. Changing the animations to do wild rotations or movements as a test still results in a local position of (0,0,0).

And a couple views of the scene graph in blender in case there's anything obviously wrong there:

[image]
[image]

The only slightly unusual thing is that the bag mesh node isn't a child of the penguin body, but it does have the armature modifier on it as you can see. (The "bag" bone appears as well though it's collapsed)

I would love to know what exactly is going wrong with either the export or import to make the animation fail to get sampled, but honestly I'd be just as happy hearing about any ideas for a quick fix that involve resampling animations, recalculating the armature, or anything else worth trying that don't involve starting from scratch and just having the bag node in there to begin with.

Comment: UPDATE: I wouldn't say I solved the root issue, but I did figure out a problem. The bone named "bag" is not actually the correct bone that is being animated. It is an unnamed bone that doesn't appear inside blender itself. 

In fact, I'm reading in about 18 bones via my importer, when in blender there are only 12 bones, so there are extra bones in there for some reason. However "bag" is the only one that seems to be incorrect. An invisible parent? Not really sure. It's a lead, at least.